# How to scroll down inside an element in vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, html

Say a scrollbox includes a `ul` with about 50 `li` elements. The moment I scroll down to it's end it shows other 50 elements, and again and again, until there are no more li's to show and the reached total is about 1000.

The main identifier of that element is `.uiScrollableArea`.

How could I scroll down inside it automatically?

I found this jQuery that didn't work:

```
setInterval(()=>{
    document.querySelector('.uiScrollableArea').scrollBottom;
}, 1500);
```

I desire a vanilla solution like this, just for my element:

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```

This didn't scroll down and outputted 0 in console:

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.querySelector('.uiScrollableArea').scrollHeight);
```

How could this be done in vanilla JS?

Comment: First of all this:
```
setInterval(()=>{
    document.querySelector('.uiScrollableArea').scrollBottom;
}, 1500);
```
Is not jQuery, it's plain JavaScript no libraries.

Comment: Second. Provide some HTML example please.